# Unable to remove head node and returning items from the list in c++

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, linked-list

I want to print the list in reversed order as well as remove the list item one by one and in the end the list should be empty.

My output is not as the requirement so in that case:

I am trying to assign `Head->temp` to `temp` `int` and `return` it in `RemoveHead()` function. BUt, i am not able to as it is giving an error which is `Invalid conversion from int to NodePtr`. Also, `L1.RemoveHead()` in `main()` function is not even working and `L1.Print()` is not printing `"List is empty."` which is the last line of `int main()`.

This is my output:

```
===== Testing Step-1 =====
Testing default constructor...
List is empty.

Testing AddHead()...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Testing IsEmpty() and RemoveHead()...
```

and this should be the output:

```
===== Testing Step-1 =====
Testing default constructor...
List is empty.

Testing AddHead()...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Testing IsEmpty() and RemoveHead()...
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
List is empty.
```

This is my programming:

```
int main()
{ 
    cout << "===== Testing Step-1 =====\n";
    cout << "Testing default constructor...\n";
    LinkedList L1;
    L1.Print(); // should be empty
    cout<<"\nTesting AddHead()...\n";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << i << ' ';
        L1.AddHead(i);
    }
    cout << endl;
    L1.Print();
    while(!L1.IsEmpty())
        cout << L1.RemoveHead()<< ' '; 
    cout << endl; 
    L1.Print();
}

void LinkedList::AddHead(int Item)
{ 
    NodePtr newnode;
    newnode = new Node;
    newnode->Item = Item;
    newnode->Next = Head;
    Head = newnode;
}

int LinkedList::RemoveHead()
{
    if(Head==NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Error Occured. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {       
        NodePtr temp;
        temp->Item = Head->Item;
        temp = Head;
        Head = Head->Next;
        delete temp;
        return temp;
    }
}
bool LinkedList::IsEmpty()
{
    return Head==NULL;
}

void LinkedList::Print()
{
    if (Head==0)
    {
        cout << "Empty error ." ;
    }
    else
    {
        NodePtr crnt;
        crnt = Head;
        while(crnt!= NULL)
        {
        cout << crnt->Item << " ";
        crnt = crnt->Next;
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't reason about a class definition that isn't available to us. Post a [mcve], please.

Comment: Possibly problem in the setting pointers. Could you add source of the 
    LinkedList::AddHead() ?

Comment: just addedd. please have a look

Comment: Why did you use the same variable for temporary storing both Head and Head->item in the RemoveHead function?

Comment: `NodePtr temp;   temp = Head->Item;` This is one of the errors `temp` is a `NodePtr` and assigning to `Item` which is an `int`. Use a different variable to return the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `LinkedList::RemoveHead()` you can't access the instance pointed by the `temp` `NodePtr` pointer after it has been deleted. You need to save the integer result to an additional variable:

```
int LinkedList::RemoveHead()
{
    if (! Head)
    {
        cerr << "Error Occured. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        int result = Head->Item;
        NodePtr temp = Head;
        Head = Head->Next;
        delete temp;
        return result;
    }
}
```